Suggest + infinitive?
I think this grammar book is wrong. I checked it in many grammar books and in the Cambridge site.
Gerunds and Infinitives: Things You Should Know (Questions ... Michael Rumi Leigh · 2023
g) She suggested going for a walk in the park. (infinitive)  ?  This is already correct
Answer :
g) She suggested to go for a walk in the park.
Here is a copy of the page :


She suggested going for a walk. OR She suggested you go for a walk. suggest doesn't take "to". Neither do several other verbs like recommend and advise. I don't understand how you organized that page. The second group has some odd things in it. But we don't usually do homework here.

I'm not sure it's saying that the first group are all mistakes that need to be corrected; it's just asking you to convert them for practice. Many of these have the opposite problem: B, D, E, and F are more idiomatic as infinitives. I don't think the book means to present the answers as improvements or even necessarily as idiomatic.

You might post whatever earlier section gave instructions for the exercise.

You're right that it's wrong. One cannot "suggest (someone) to do" something.

She suggested ❌ to go for a walk in the park.

These are all okay though:

She suggested going for a walk in the park.
She suggested they go for a walk in the park.
She suggested a walk in the park.

In the same way:

She suggested going to the gym after work.

is ok but when you need a subject then you need a subordinate clause with an uninflected verb (the so-called "mandative subjunctive"):

She suggested that he go to the gym after work.

